# Need help to parse "Super5Sport5Asia5" when I'm searching of occurence of SuperSportAsia?

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I have a forum spammer who keeps registering new accounts on my forum and posting his website. I already have a filter which removes all tags and spaces and looks for "supersportasia" but he is circumventing it by using "Super5Sport5Asia5" and then changing the 5s to white color so it becomes like "Super Sport Asia" with the hidden 5s. Is there a way to parse it better? It may not only be 5s it could be other chars....

Answer (score 1):

```
Super.*Sport.*Asia
```

However, I'd block by IP (range). It'll only take a minute to come up with `Mega6Fun6Europe`.

Comment: I cant do that as he uses Tor proxies

Comment: It would be interesting to benchmark it against Super((?!Sport).)*Sport((?!Asia).)*Asia This one should backtrack less.

Comment: @Stephen Wow, that looks like an unusually determined troll. You could block registration from all Tor gateways, sort of like Wikipedia does (but that would block regular registerers). Also, you could go by header characteristics, like the precise user-agent. However, I'd assume that won't be much of a hindrance for a Tor user either.

Comment: @xanatos Shouldn't be a problem, since the start with `Super` means anything not super won't be matched, will it?

Comment: @phihag Yes, clearly. The first part will delete 99.99% of the "start points"... It was more a "premature optimization what if" challenge... You know, those useless challenges that persons do :-) "my car is faster than yours" "my cellphone is better than yours" ...

Comment: I've been in this for 10 years and this is the worse troll i have seen...He even uses images hosted at tinypic to post his website url in the image. Recently I did flash cookies and in 2 days he figured it out. I already have multiple systems in place but this gets me everytime thats why I need a regex.

Answer (score 1):

You could first try with `super.*sport.*asia` case insensitive,

### But

Fighting spammer is a cat&mouse race. The regex I suggested you filters any combination of "noise" character as soon as the words are written integer.

Drawback: a legitimate message containing the above words in sequence (in any part) will be rejected

> Superman is becoming a sport hero, and is said to be born in Asia

### Also

The spammer may start complicating the message a lot

> s-u-p-e-r_s-p-o-r-t_a-s-i-a

could be still distinguished.

You would better focus on different anti-spam techniques like CAPTCHA and also don't forget to ban /24 subnets when you get your spammer

### Edit

Fear of TOR? I don't currently have reference to say, but I knew that TOR relays are publicly distinguishable. At least Wikipedia knows if you are running TOR or not. You might want to ask them, unless your spammer uses a hidden relay.

Many websites commonly ban proxies against "write" access (so you *can* read them anonymously)